# JavaScript computer algebra system

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a simple [computer algebra system (cas)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) for JavaScript but I can't find anything with google. I only need basic functionality:

- simplify expressions to some canonic form. Ability to check if two expressions are the same, i.e., a(x+y) == ax+ay
- parse mathematical formulas. I want it to be able to read expressions like ax²+4x.
- solve simple equations etc.

Do you know of such a library?

Comment: Solve simple equation: How simple? Simple operations can build unsolvable equations e.g. `x^x = 3` or `x^5 + x^3 - 6*x^2 + 3 = 0`.

Comment: BTW, try to Google for "Symbolic math".

Comment: @KennyTM Those equations aren’t unsolveable, unless you’re talking about how they have multiple solutions. Solutions: [`x^x = 3`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^x+%3D+3%3B+solve+for+x), [`x^5 + x^3 - 6*x^2 + 3 = 0`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^5+%2B+x^3+-+6*x^2+%2B+3+%3D+0%3B+solve+for+x)

Comment: Bountying, as I'm really interested in this.

Answer (score 6):

(I'm answering myself, as the bounty failed to bring attention on this.)

You might want to try [this](https://github.com/aantthony/javascript-cas) CAS, which has some good functions (although some parts are broken, use the older versions).

Comment: Readme of that library tells that it doesn't solve equations.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [nerdamer](https://github.com/jiggzson/nerdamer)

- simplification
- factoring
- expanding
- custom functions
- vectors
- matrices
- integration
- differentiation
- root solver
- interpolation

```js
//Expanding
var result = nerdamer('a*(x+y)',null,'expand');
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = '<p>'+result.text()+'</p>';
//Solving equation
var sol = nerdamer.solveEquations('0=x^2+x+a','x');
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += '<p>'+sol.toString()+'</p>';
```

```html
<script src="http://nerdamer.com/js/nerdamer.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://nerdamer.com/js/Algebra.js"></script>
<script src="http://nerdamer.com/js/Solve.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: It's just a coincidence that it shows `0.5` for `1/2` in this example, so that it doesn't seem to be a numeric solver. Try something that should return `1/3` or `sqrt(2)` instead.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Please give an example of such an equation.

Comment: I kind of understand what polkovnikov.ph is saying. At the time of his comment coefficients were represented as decimals so in reality they were approximations when used in the solver. In newer versions however this is no longer the case. 1/3 is a real ratio and sqrt(2) is no longer converted to a decimal until instructed.

Answer (score 2):

You might also look at JSolve: http://www.movss.com/~rich/jsolve/

It's written in Java and compiled to JavaScript using the GWT framework.

Answer (score 1):

I found another one that looks decent, **Coffeequate**.

- [Website](http://matthewja.com/Coffeequate/)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/MatthewJA/Coffeequate)

Answer (score 0):

To parse mathematical formula's you might give [jscc](http://jscc.jmksf.com/) a try. Solving them is left as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: Unfortunately the link to [jscc](http://jscc.jmksf.com/) is broken now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Wolframalpha API](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/). http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/documentation.html

Comment: First, Javascript cannot access external web sites. Second, W|A is not properly a CAS. Third, its ToS forbide the access by automated means.

Comment: First, XMLHttpRequest on Samsung can access external web sites. Second part is true, but you can extract symbolic interpretaton from response. Third, what part of http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/termsofuse.html prohibit automated access?

Comment: Sorry, about XMLHttpRequest you right. I confuse this question with about SmarTV. Yes, you need to proxy requests to wolfram API to get results in JavaScript. This can be done by setting up ReverseProxy on site where your project is hosted.

Comment: You're right about the automated access part - I confused the W|A ToS with its API ToS.

Answer (score 0):

To add a solid library to the list: http://mathjs.org/

It even helped to solve a problem with [complex calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25329786/1066234).

Comment: But it is in no way a computer algebra system. No matter what kind of obscure arithmetic was done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Algebrite seems to be a very good one:
[http://algebrite.org](http://algebrite.org/)

There is a list of more than 7 other CAS libraries for JS at the bottom of their website.